# How can I improve this simple image gallery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a basic image gallery with simple `html`, `css` and `js`

This is the code so far.

```js
$('.navigation-1').click(function() {
  $('.cat-1').css("opacity", "1");
  $('.cat-2').css("opacity", "0");
  $('.cat-3').css("opacity", "0");
  $('.cat-4').css("opacity", "0");
});

$('.navigation-2').click(function() {
  $('.cat-1').css("opacity", "0");
  $('.cat-2').css("opacity", "1");
  $('.cat-3').css("opacity", "0");
  $('.cat-4').css("opacity", "0");
});

$('.navigation-3').click(function() {
  $('.cat-3').css("opacity", "1");
  $('.cat-1').css("opacity", "0");
  $('.cat-2').css("opacity", "0");
  $('.cat-4').css("opacity", "0");
});

$('.navigation-4').click(function() {
  $('.cat-4').css("opacity", "1");
  $('.cat-1').css("opacity", "0");
  $('.cat-2').css("opacity", "0");
  $('.cat-3').css("opacity", "0");
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.cat {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Show a picture at load */
.cat-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navigation">
  <button class="nav navigation-1">Cat 1</button>
  <button class="nav navigation-2">Cat 2</button>
  <button class="nav navigation-3">Cat 3</button>
  <button class="nav navigation-4">Cat 4</button>
</div>

<img class="cat cat-1" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="">

<img class="cat cat-2" src="http://placekitten.com/300/201" alt="">

<img class="cat cat-3" src="http://placekitten.com/301/200" alt="">

<img class="cat cat-4" src="http://placekitten.com/301/201" alt="">
```

How do I dynamically generate the buttons and hide the other images, when one image is shown.

I used `opacity` to show and hide images, but feel free to use whatever suits you best.

I'm sure the `this` keyword is useful here, but how?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions, making this question too broad.  Also as a general rule, "how do I make this better" are assumed to be off topic for Stack Overflow, as "making it better" has the assumption that it currently works, and you are trying to refactor it to improve it, which is not an "issue".

Comment: Look for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Taplar - I see where you're coming from, but I think there is a grey area on SO where I think it's legitimate to say "it's working, but I know it could be better, I just don't know how"

Comment: I'll use that for future reference @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks

Comment: @freefaller "I just don't know how", in the context of "how to make it better", is too broad.  There is no defined answer for satisfying that question.

Comment: @Taplar - I take your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following... where I've added a "data-index" attribute to the "navigation" buttons.

The on button click you hide all "cat" items, and then show the required one by targeting it using the "data-index" attribute.

```js
$('.nav').click(function() {
  $('.cat').css("opacity", "0");
  var id = $(this).data("index");
  $('.cat-' + id).css("opacity", "1");
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.cat {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Show a picture at load */
.cat-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navigation">
  <button class="nav" data-index="1">Cat 1</button>
  <button class="nav" data-index="2">Cat 2</button>
  <button class="nav" data-index="3">Cat 3</button>
  <button class="nav" data-index="4">Cat 4</button>
</div>

<img class="cat cat-1" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="">

<img class="cat cat-2" src="http://placekitten.com/300/201" alt="">

<img class="cat cat-3" src="http://placekitten.com/301/200" alt="">

<img class="cat cat-4" src="http://placekitten.com/301/201" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// get all cats
const cats = document.querySelectorAll('.cat')
// gets nav container
const nav = document.querySelector('.navigation')

// for each cat
for (let i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
  // select current cat
  const chosenCat = cats[i];
  // create button for it
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  // add some text to button
  button.innerHTML = `Cat ${i + 1}`;
  // create onclick function that hides all cats and reveals current
  button.onclick = () => {
    // use Array.prototype.slice.call because you cant iterate the NodeList
    Array.prototype.slice.call(cats).forEach(cat => cat.style.opacity = 0);
    chosenCat.style.opacity = 1;
  };
  // add button to nav container
  nav.appendChild(button);
}
// reveal initial cat
cats[0].style.opacity = 1;
```

```css
.cat {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
}

.navigation {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="cat cat-1" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="">
<img class="cat cat-2" src="http://placekitten.com/300/201" alt="">
<img class="cat cat-3" src="http://placekitten.com/301/200" alt="">
<img class="cat cat-4" src="http://placekitten.com/301/201" alt="">

<div class="navigation">
</div>
```